# Send a voice message to incoming call

Tags: android, call, telephonymanager

**How to Handle an incoming call with sending a voice message instead of picking the call in android ?**
 I am developing an answering machine for android and need help to handle incoming call interruption..

Comment: Till I know, Its not possible!!